# Visual Studio 2015 hangs on multiple build deletion

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 hangs on attempt to delete a lot of builds at once through Build Explorer untill Team Foundation Server closes a connection.

Is there any working and fast way to delete more than 300 builds?

Some possibly significant info about installation:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
- JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2 Build 104.0.20151218.120627
- Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools   14.0

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? It seems you tried to delete XAML completed builds, correct? When you perform deletion, do you select all deleteOptions? If you select all deleteOptions, have you checked whether the drop size is big?

Comment: @Cece - MSFT It'was TFS 2013 and old XAML completed builds. I selected all deleteOptions. It seams like drop size was not big - builds were StyleCop checks.

Answer (score 1):

Including deleting builds in VS, you can also:

- delete builds in TFS Web Access.
- Use [Delete Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244360(v=vs.100).aspx) to delete buils.

Syntax：

```
TFSBuild delete /collection:teamProjectCollectionUrl /builddefinition:definitionSpec buildnumber[buildNumber...] [/deleteOptions:deleteOptions] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/preview]
```

If you don't need completed builds longer than a certain number of days, you can consider set retention policies. Your retention policies automatically delete old completed builds to minimize clutter. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/define/retention

Comment: Now I cannot test alternative methods you suggested, because I have deleted the builds splitting it in little (10-30 items) chunks.